# how kernel manages virtual memory

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu, virtual-memory, microkernel

I just wanted to know how kernel actually deny proccess from access another memory region for example if **IP** register is set to `0x41414141` isnt that direct cpu instruction how can the kernel deny the cpu from accessing that address in the **physical memory**

### another question:

when debugging an application the addresses we see and libc and shared lib addesses are in the virtual memory, how then cpu access a memory that is not exist ? or how actually kernel tell the cpu the location of the region in the physical memory at runtime

Also another question, in x86_32 arch syscalls issues by int 0x80 how kernel preserve a software interrupt number for itself how that happens

Comment: **Too many** questions in the single question post. Try to concentrate on the single problem. And search before the posting the question.

Comment: Even IP refers to virtual address space, private to each process.  0x41414141 refers to different physical page in one space than in another, or even no page at all.  Kernel sets up page tables to map virtual to physical.  The CPU consults (and caches) the page table to convert the virtual addresses to physical on-the-fly.

Comment: If code refers to a virtual address that does not map to physical, a page fault occurs.

Comment: I'm totally confused by these questions. What is a "memory region" in this context?